# Perl: Searching for an intermediate directory name

Tags: perl

I am trying to find an efficient way to find out and intermediate directory name. For example I want to get "x2" directory name in the following path /x1/x2/x3 giving the path /x1 and the name x3.

NOTE: I do not know the full path /x1/x2/x3. I only know /x1 and the name x3. In another word, I am trying to search for the parent directory of the subdirectory x3 under the /x1 path.

Would you please help?
Thank You!

Comment: This is a very basic operation that can be done with either a regex or `split("/",$file)`. But, are all the filenames of the form `/x1/x2/x3`? Do you have any that are [say] `/x1/x2/x3/x4` [or longer]? And, what would you want in that case? It seems to me that `/x1` and `x3` [and discarding `x2`] aren't as useful as `/x1/x2` and `x3`--I'm trying to imagine the use case.

Comment: This is a trivial problem. Do you know any Perl at all? What research have you done, and why did the results not satisfy you?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you look at the core [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) module

The `splitdir` class method should help you

Answer (score 2):

Go with *Borodin*'s solution. But in case you don't want use a module, split the path with `/`:

```
my $dir = "/x1/x2/x3";
my $paths = (split "/", $dir)[2];
print $paths, "\n";
```

Output:

```
x2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but It is not what I am trying to do. Actually, I do not know the path /x1/x2/x3. what I only know is the path  /x1 and the name x3. In another word I am trying to search for the parent directory that contains the x3 subdirectory under the /x1 path